# Remove results based on other table

Tags: mysql, sql

I currently have a query displaying the top users in my game by most money.

```
$q = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT `money`, `name`, `id` FROM `users` WHERE `money` > 0 ORDER BY `money` DESC LIMIT 10");
$r = 1;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($q)) {
    //Code here.
    ++$r;
}
```

Where `$r` is the rank of the user (from 1-10).

What I'm trying to do is filter out users who are currently banned on the game. There is no column in the `users` table for whether or not a user is banned, but there is a separate `bans` table that looks like this:

```
bans
`id` INT(11) PRIMARY AUTO-INCREMENT
`user` INT(11)
`reason` TEXT
`length` INT(11)
```

The `user` value in the `bans` table is the exact same as the `id` value in the `users` table.

I'm trying to filter out all users from the first query if they exist in the `bans` table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `not exists` query for example:

```
SELECT `money`, `name`, `id` 
FROM `users` u 
WHERE `money` > 0 
  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Bans b WHERE b.user = u.id)
ORDER BY `money` DESC 
LIMIT 10
```

This would remove the banned users from the result which is what I think you want - if it's the other way around just remove the `not`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `left join` for that:

```
SELECT `money`, `name`, ´users`.`id` FROM `users`  left join `bans` on user.id = bans.user WHERE bans.is is null and`money` > 0 ORDER BY `money` DESC LIMIT 10");
```

Comment: You can't really say that `you have to use` a left join... You can do it using any join, or not in or not exists, or set operators :)